# Releasing Cursors using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, cursor

I am working with ArcObjects, in particular the ICursor Interface. I am creating a cursor and looping through a query's result set. My problem/concern is how to close or delete or release the cursor once I'm done looping through the query's result set. The query is being passed into a Sql workspace (via ISqlWorkspace interface). Code is as follows

```c#
ISqlWorkspace pSQL_WS = myWorkspace as ISqlWorkspace;                
ICursor pCursor = pSQL_WS.OpenQueryCursor(strQuery);
string cursorResults = "";
IRow pRow;

while ((pRow = pCursor.NextRow()) != null)
{
  int fc = pRow.Fields.FieldCount;
  for (int x = 0; x < fc; x++)
  {
    cursorResults += pRow.get_Value(x).ToString() + "     ";
  }
    cursorResults += Environment.NewLine;
}
_textElement.Text = Convert.ToString(cursorResults);
```

I'm actually taking the results of the query and placing them in a text element. I'm thinking after the last line is where I'd want to close/delete/release my cursor, but I'm just not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 5):

To release a cursor you need to use [ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), see [this article from Esri help (9.2)](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/fe9f7423-2100-4c70-8bd6-f4f16d5ce8c0.htm) which is still valid.

Edited into your code:

```c#
ISqlWorkspace pSQL_WS = myWorkspace as ISqlWorkspace;    
ICursor pCursor = pSQL_WS.OpenQueryCursor(strQuery);
string cursorResults = "";
IRow pRow;

while ((pRow = pCursor.NextRow()) != null)
{
  int fc = pRow.Fields.FieldCount;
  for (int x = 0; x < fc; x++)
  {
    cursorResults += pRow.get_Value(x).ToString() + "     ";
  }
    cursorResults += Environment.NewLine;
}
_textElement.Text = Convert.ToString(cursorResults);
//release the row and cursor locks
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pRow);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pCursor);
```

Releasing these locks is important otherwise the workspace/feature class is locked for the life of the tool (and if in ArcCatalog or ArcMap persist until the application is closed) and will prevent deleting/renaming/adding fields...

To test if a feature class is already locked use [ISchemaLock.GetCurrentSchemaLocks](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007zs000000) which should be tested before adding fields or attempting to rename/delete the feature class.